# arranging spans within a div

Tags: html, css

In my web application, I have some divs and spans that make table like structure.
the pseudo code is,

```
<head>
<style>
span{
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
}
    .tblbody
{
        font-family:'Segoe UI';
    font-size:20px;
    color:#2A2A2A ;
    padding : 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left:9px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <span style="width: 240px;" class="tblbody">
    <span style="width: 240px;" class="tblbody">asia</span></span>
    <span><span><br>
    <span style="width: 240px;" class="tblbody">india</span></span>
    <br><span><br>
    <span style="width: 240px;" class="tblbody">china</span</span>
    <br><span><br><span style="width: 240px;" class="tblbody">pakisthan</span></span><br><span><br>
    <span style="width: 240px;" class="tblbody">bangladesh</span></span><br></span>
</body>
```

In the first row, the span that contains the continent name is moving downwards leaving space above it.
how can I move the span upwards?
thanx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write **vertical-align:top** to your **span**. Write like this:

```
span{
        display:inline-block;
        width:auto;
        vertical-align:top
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have padding-top: 5px try changin it to padding-top: 0px